# Python read() works with UTF-8 but readlines() "doesn't"

Tags: python, utf-8, io

So, I am working with a (huge) UTF-8 encoded file. The first thing I do with it it's get it's lines in a list using the File Object **readlines()** method. However when I use the print command for debugging I get things like, for example, *\xc3* etc.

Here's a really small example that replicates my problem; I created a t.txt file that contains only the text "Clara Martínez"

```py
f = open("t.txt", "r")
s = f.read()
print s
Clara Martínez
#If I do the following however
lines = f.readlines()
for l in lines:
    print l
['Clara Mart\xc3\xadnez']
#write however works fine!
f2 = open("t2.txt", "w")
for l in lines:
    f2.write(l)
f2.close()
f1.close()
```

And then I open the "t2.txt", the string is correct, i.e: Clara Martínez.
Is there any way to "make" readlines() work as read()?

Comment: What if I told you `\xc3\xad` is `í`?

Comment: You should probably use `io.open` with `encoding='utf-8'`. That'll read the file as Unicode with the proper encoding, instead of a series of bytes that may or may not print the way you expect.

Answer (score 4):

You claim that this:

```
lines = f.readlines()
for l in lines:
    print l
```

Will result in this:

```
['Clara Mart\xc3\xadnez']
```

This is not true, it will not. I think you made a mistake in your code, and wrote this:

```
lines = f.readlines()
for l in lines:
    print lines
```

That code will give the result you say, assuming the file contains only one line with the text `'Clara Mart\xc3\xadnez'`.

Comment: This is a nitpick on the formulation of the question which does not help figuring out the answer. This answer should have been a comment instead.